# Finding and replacing template-embracing typenames (Foo <...>) in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Vscode, I have the following type pattern:

```
Foo<Bar> ....

Foo<Bar> ....
```

I want to remove `Foo<` and `>`, but retain `Bar`.
What is the best way to proceed with this?

Note: `Bar` may also be templated

Comment: regex does not keep track of matching braces, you need a parser to get it correct in all cases.

Comment: Okay, so does that mean that there is no way to solve this from the find and replace interface of vscode? Are there well developed tools for this issue that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Regex was the answer:

Vscode regex search string:

```
Foo<(.*)>
```

Replacement string:

```
$1
```

Parentheses captures match into `$1`, `.*` matches anything.
(This does not solve it for nested `<, >`)